# How to restore the menu state on configuration change

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I have 2 menu items (filter button and search button) that allow to filter or search within a list. When a list item is selected, it is given to the view throught the viewModel's LiveData called `listItemSelected`, when this happen, we move from the `ListFragment` to the `DetailFragment` and hide the 2 buttons from the menu, as they aren't relevent here.

My problem is on configuration change, for example on screen rotation, the old activity is destroyed, and the new `Activity.onCreate()` function is called before `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, so I don't know how can I set back the menu state properly.

Simplified code sample below, right now it just crash on `filterMenuItem.isVisible = it == null` because `filterMenuItem` is not initialized at this point.

```kotlin
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
    private lateinit var filterMenuItem: MenuItem
    private lateinit var searchMenuItem: MenuItem

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = getViewModel { injector.myViewModel }
        viewModel.listItemSelected.observe(this, Observer {
            filterMenuItem.isVisible = it == null
            searchMenuItem.isVisible = it == null
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        menu!!.apply {
            filterMenuItem = findItem(R.id.main_menu_filter)
            searchMenuItem = findItem(R.id.main_menu_search)
        }

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about observing data after you initialized the `MenuItem`'s:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
    private lateinit var filterMenuItem: MenuItem
    private lateinit var searchMenuItem: MenuItem

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = getViewModel { injector.myViewModel }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        menu!!.apply {
            filterMenuItem = findItem(R.id.main_menu_filter)
            searchMenuItem = findItem(R.id.main_menu_search)
        }

        // observe after the menu items are initialized
        viewModel.listItemSelected.observe(this, Observer {
            filterMenuItem.isVisible = it == null
            searchMenuItem.isVisible = it == null
        })

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is so basic I didn't even thought about it, for whatever reason I put absolutly all my `observe` in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Yes sure. I will just wait a bit to see if someone have another idea and do some research about android lifecycle. Somehow I figured out way harder things like Dagger or RxJava but android lifecycle is still a mystery to me ahaha.